# How to reposition the responsive navigation in css

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create the header and navigation for a page in creating, but my navigation appears either hidden or not showing.

I have already tried adding the position and top attributes to the css code, but without success.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs    /font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0    /css/all.css' integrity='sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU' crossorigin='anonymous'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .topnav {
       overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    .topnav a {
       float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px; 
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #cc0066;
      color: black;
    }

        .active {
      background-color: #cc0066;;
      color: white;
    }

        .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <header id="header-full-top" class="header-full hidden-xs">
      <div class="columns">
       <ul class="price">
         <li class="header"><img src="img/logo1.png" width="75%"></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="columns">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header"><img src="img/slogan2.png" width="40%"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header"><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="sellers.html">Sellers</a>
      <a href="buyers.html">Buyers</a>
      <a href="information.html">Information</a>
      <a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
      <a href="#contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h2>Main content title</h2>
      <p>main content </p>
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
   </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

What I would like is for the navigation to appear under the header images.

social.css code:

```
/* table */
 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

/* Create three columns of equal width */
.columns {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Style the list */
.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Add shadows on hover */
.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

/* Pricing header */
.price .header {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* List items */
.price li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Grey list item */
.price .grey {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* The "Sign Up" button */(mot used)
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Change the width of the three columns to 100%
(to stack horizontally on small screens) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .columns {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/*icons*/
.fa {
  margin: 15px 0 0 30px;
  padding: 20px ;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
 }

 .fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;

}
.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
```

### }

Screenshot of missing navigation:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNFUH.jpg)

Comment: your using the navbar from 3 schools?

Comment: yes, just for speed and testing reasons at the moment- why is there a problem with that?

Comment: its working now?

Comment: @Harish Soni- Thank you for the answer, but I cant see what changes you have made to the original code.

Comment: I did not answer I edited your code and changed it to a snippet so anyone can see the results.

Comment: @godfather - no.  I think it could be something to do with the social.css I will add this to to initial post.

Comment: @godfather - Hi there. So I have added the social. css code at the bottom of the original post, but not sure whats happening. If you get it to work, please can you show me what you changed, many thanks in advance.

Comment: you still have the problem? i have add it to vs code its working fine whats the specific problem?

Comment: @godfather - as i mentioned before, on my localhost the Nav bar doesnt show- how can i post here a screenshot to show you?

Comment: when you click on the button nothing appear thats it?

Comment: @godfather - No, the whole navigation is not showing at all, im not sure if its because its hidden, or there is an error in my code.

Comment: i see now because the code you provided its working even i created the social.css on my vscode so even on desktop size its hidden

Comment: what is the nav.css?

Comment: This is driving me made. - I can't seem to see where the error is. Its not rendering the inline css. - The css for styling the icons works. I have tried removing the inline and adding an external css with that code, but still no success. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: @godfather -  ignore the nav.css - all i did as i said the replace the inline css with an external css, but this didnt work.

Comment: do you have a repository of this file? because the code i have for the moment is perfect

Comment: @godfather -  I want the nav menu to appear above "main content title" - thats what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @godfather - give me a moment. - I think I have found how to work this. - how do i add you to project?

Comment: @godfather -  file/ path... - https://github.com/lukeMersh/quickcompletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the header is overlapping so you should set display property to #header-full-top {display:flex;}